# On the analogy between RF cavities and parallel RLC circuits

Tags: particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-circuits, accelerator-physics, particle-accelerators

Every superconductive radio-frequency cavity can be seen as a parallel RLC circuit, as shown in the picture below:
[image]

The thing is every *parallel* RLC circuit acts like a band-stop filter: at the resonance frequency, its impedance is maximum and the current is minimum.

The purpose of these cavities on the other hand should be to have an $E$ field as high as possible... but *how* is it possible?